# python list of lists to firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have a list that contains lists. I want to save it in firestore under a map that exists

list:

```
[['1', 'B'],
 ['5', 'E'],
 ['7', 'J']]
```

Output needed in firestore:

```
letter_count (map)
     1:'B'
     5:'E'
     7:'J'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to store lists within lists in firebase, unfortunately (more info on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59068112/8612435). What you can do is convert that list into a dictionary and pass that data into firebase instead:

```
# convert to dictionary
mydict =  {}

for i in range(len(mylist)):
  mydict[mylist[i][0]] = mylist[i][1]

print(mydict)

# push to firebase
db.collection('collection-name').document('document-name').set({'letter_count': mydict})
```

(Note: I took inspiration in multidimensional list conversion to dictionary through this post: [convert multidimensional list into dictionary python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186069/convert-multidimensional-list-into-dictionary-python/55186139))

Answer (score 1):

Convert list into dictionary before you update it.

```
letter_case = {x[0]: x[1] for x in [['1', 'B'], ['5', 'E'], ['7', 'J']]}
print(letter_case)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `update()` to add if the list is not existing in document and update the field if it is existing, for example:

**UPDATE**:
convert into dictionary based on [@Sabari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69390140/8753991):

```
letter_case = {x[0]: x[1] for x in [['1', 'B'], ['5', 'E'], ['7', 'J']]}

doc_ref = db.collection(u'testcol').document(u'testdoc')
doc_ref.update({'letter_count': letter_case })
```